# Array Value Must Start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Here's my create table code:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, firstName Varchar(30), lastName Varchar(30), street TEXT, city Varchar(50), state Varchar(2), zip INTEGER);')
```

And here's my Upsert Function:

```
def upsert_customer(customer):
    cur=conn.cursor()

    if 'id' in customer:
        cur.execute('UPDATE Customers SET firstName= %s, lastName = %s, street=%s, city=%s, state=%s, zip=%s WHERE id =%s;' , (customer['firstName'], customer['lastName'], customer['street'], customer['city'], customer['state'], customer['zip']))
    else:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO Customers( firstName, lastName, street,city,state,zip) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);' , (customer['firstName'], customer['lastName'], customer['street'], customer['city'], customer['state'], customer['zip']))

    conn.commit()
```

When I add a customer from a webpage, I get the error message, and in the web page it displays the following error: " Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

The program is to complete implementation of functions that connects a web page to our PostgreSQL in ElephantSQL. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Err.. in the `if` part, you have seven `%s` placeholders, but provide only six values: `customer['id']` is missing.

Comment: Thank you, however even with that updated, i'm getting the same error.

Comment: What does the entire request look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means?

Answer (score 1):

Your table definition does not reconcile with declared error - you have no arrays in it and yet the error you see clearly comes from bad array definition, eg:

```
t=# select 'not array'::text[];
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "not array"
LINE 1: select 'not array'::text[];
               ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```